Getting StaleElementReferenceException while trying to access the "Raw" button on GitHub using Selenium
Title basically, getting a StaleElementReferenceException while trying to access the "Raw" button on GitHub using Selenium.
.types__StyledButton-sc-ws60qy-0 and .dupbIv are the classes of the button I am trying to click on.
What exactly could be causing this?
def clickRaw(file_path):
    driver.get(file_path)
    delay = 10

    try:
        raw = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".types__StyledButton-sc-ws60qy-0.dupbIv")))
        raw.click()
    except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
        print("Too much time")
        return

    pageSource = driver.page_source
    pageSource = f"{pageSource}"
    if "password" in pageSource:
        print(f"Password found @: {file_path}")

I was trying to have selenium click on the "Raw" button, and it resulted in a StaleElementReferenceException
